# Ngram model and perplexity in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

To put my question in context, I would like to train and test/compare several (neural) language models. In order to focus on the models rather than data preparation I chose to use the Brown corpus from nltk and train the Ngrams model provided with the nltk as a baseline (to compare other LM against).

So my first question is actually about a behaviour of the Ngram model of nltk that I find suspicious.
Since the code is rather short I pasted it here:

```
import nltk

print "... build"
brown = nltk.corpus.brown
corpus = [word.lower() for word in brown.words()]

# Train on 95% f the corpus and test on the rest
spl = 95*len(corpus)/100
train = corpus[:spl]
test = corpus[spl:]

# Remove rare words from the corpus
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(w for w in train)
vocabulary = set(map(lambda x: x[0], filter(lambda x: x[1] >= 5, fdist.iteritems())))

train = map(lambda x: x if x in vocabulary else "*unknown*", train)
test = map(lambda x: x if x in vocabulary else "*unknown*", test)

print "... train"
from nltk.model import NgramModel
from nltk.probability import LidstoneProbDist

estimator = lambda fdist, bins: LidstoneProbDist(fdist, 0.2) 
lm = NgramModel(5, train, estimator=estimator)

print "len(corpus) = %s, len(vocabulary) = %s, len(train) = %s, len(test) = %s" % ( len(corpus), len(vocabulary), len(train), len(test) )
print "perplexity(test) =", lm.perplexity(test)
```

What I find very suspicious is that I get the following results:

```
... build
... train
len(corpus) = 1161192, len(vocabulary) = 13817, len(train) = 1103132, len(test) = 58060
perplexity(test) = 4.60298447026
```

With a perplexity of 4.6 it seems Ngram modeling is very good on that corpus. If my interpretation is correct then the model should be able to guess the correct word in roughly 5 tries on average (although there are 13817 possibilities...). If you could share your experience on the value of this perplexity (I don't really believe it)? I did not find any complaints on the ngram model of nltk on the net ( but maybe I do it wrong). Do you know a good alternatives to NLTK for Ngram models and computing perplexity?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the implementation of ngrams in NLTK is wrong. SRILM (http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/) give a perplexity of ~150 (much more credible). Still, given the popularity of the NLTK I am surprised nobody experienced this earlier...

Answer (score 4):

You are getting a low perplexity because you are using a pentagram model. If you'd use a bigram model your results will be in more regular ranges of about 50-1000 (or about 5 to 10 bits).

Given your comments, are you using NLTK-3.0alpha? You shouldn't, at least not for language modeling:

https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues?labels=model

As a matter of fact, the whole `model` module has been dropped from the NLTK-3.0a4 pre-release until the issues are fixed.

Comment: Still, a perplexity of 4 on the brown corpus using 5-grams is not realistic at all. Is anyone able to reproduce this result? Seems to me the n-gram implementation is flawed or there is something I don't get.

Comment: hmm, are you using NLTK2.0 or 3.0? See my "extra" answer above.